# How to copy triggers/projects from one spreadsheet to another?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I'm attempting to create a spreadsheet that needs to be copied a bunch of times from within one spreadsheet but each copy is also meant to have triggers within it and it appears that this is harder than I initially thought.

The actual project involves an editable database that takes from single sheet spreadsheets each one a copy of a single sheet from the main spreadsheet and the whole thing then needs to be duplicated.

I first just tried to create a copy of the first spreadsheet but it seems that the project that the triggers are contained within doesn't copy over. I have tried using installable triggers but it seems that you cant do this easily from within another spreadsheet as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32320622/can-a-standalone-script-create-a-trigger-for-another-script-which-is-bound-to-a?rq=1) (I don't really understand the answer to this question). I have also looked at the possibility of copying the project from one spreadsheet to another but this also just seems like a dead end.

I can appreciate that this is quite vague but I really have no idea what to do about this and any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Copying spreadsheets and the code that comes with them is a great way to end up with 40 script projects (all of which are different actual script projects, even if they have identical content) that all need to be changed when one update to your code is done. Better to pursue the G Suite add-on model, so that copying the spreadsheet does not copy the script, authorization needs to be given just once, updates need to be made only once, and the add-on can use its on open method to 1) assert if it can do something with the bound document, and 2) if so and not done yet, create triggers.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm I am not sure about copying triggers over. (I normally just use onOpen triggers for menu items.) However I can confirm the following bit of code copies the spreadsheet and all of it's embedded scripts.

```
function copyTemplate() {

//A file needs a name
var fileName = "Your File Name Here"

//Get the ID of the Master Spreadsheet (This script is embedded, you can change to get by id.)
var id = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();

//Get the Destination folder by ID
var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("YOUR_ID_HERE")

//Get the master template, make a copy in the destination folder.
DriveApp.getFileById(id).makeCopy(fileName, destFolder)

}//END OF FUNCTION
```